# Weird url pathing for autodesk forge db jsons

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've implemented offline viewing based on the tutorial and github [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/working-seamlessly-onlineoffline-when-developing-apps-with-the-forge-viewer-.html). The problem I'm having is forge is looking for the db jsons in an odd location that makes url pathing awkward. The files in particular are 'objects_attrs.json.gz', 'objects_vals.json.gz', 'objects_offs.json.gz', 'objects_ids.json.gz', 'objects_avs.json.gz'. For some reason the forge viewer strips two layers of directories off the url then looks for the files there. Afterword Forge looks for the files in the original location but, looks for the straight json instead of the gziped jsons.

This can be handled in a few hacky ways like creating two arbitrary parent directories in the url and accepting files at the higher url as well. Or unzipping the gzips and saving them in location. But, these kind of hacks could easily be unstable if I'm not exactly right about the forge implementation.

Is there any reason these files are searched for in a different location? For example are these files also used by the 2d files not just the 3d files? Are there other files like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the .svf file, say it's Design.svf.  Rename it to Design.zip, and then upzip the file.  This will get you the manifest.json.

Inside the manifest.json file, you'll file the URI's of all the files, including the one's you mentioned (the property database files).

Modify the URI as you wish, save the manifest.json file and re-zip it back up and rename it back to Design.svf.

If you got the URI path matching your file-system, then those property files will now load correctly.

Good luck!